# Test Explorer (VS) shows '<Unknown project>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

Everthing below is made in VS2019, using .NET Framework 4.7 and NUnit + NUnit3TestAdapter

I created an assembly called Exitus.Tests, and added a few unit tests. However, do to some issues with Nuget, that I could not solve, I made another project called Exitus.UnitTests and removed the once file I had in the old project (including changing the namespace).

Now the new test project showed op correctly in the explorer, but a "ghost" of the old project remained:

[image: Visual Studio test explorer]

If I try to run the test, the output window shows the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The following TestContainer was not found 'C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repositories\Expire\Exitus.Tests\bin\Debug\Exitus.Tests.dll'
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.d__46.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQueryByTestsBase.d__6.MoveNext()
>      (...)

The stack trace is a lot longer, but the curious thing is the second line, stating that it could not find the test container at `\Exitus.Tests\bin\Debug\Exitus.Tests.dll`. This is the name of the old test project, which I removed and deleted. I have searched my entire project for the term `Exitus.Tests` and it returns no results.

Is there anyway to forcefully remove this 'ghost' project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545634/how-do-you-fix-specflow-unknown-project-issue-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 386, accepted):

1. Close <kbd>Visual Studio</kbd>.
2. Delete the `*.testlog` files in:
   *solutionfolder*\.vs\*solution name*\v16\TestStore\*number*.

Comment: After much feedback, I have decided to change this to the acceptet answer. I still used Alex B.'s answer, which works fine as long as you don have critical files in your git repository, which may not tracked.

Comment: `.vs ` is a hidden directory. Make sure to set your file explorer to see hidden directories

Comment: 99% of visual studio errors are solved by removing magic hidden files in the .vs folder, or the windows temp / roaming / local folder. :C

Comment: I asked internally about this. Apparently the problem's fixed in 16.5.

Comment: I did not get it to work with this answer. I had to use Alex B's answer.

Comment: This seems to work after the first restart, but the project / tests reappear after restarting again.

Comment: this may be a bit over dramatic. but thank you jesus!

Comment: I wonder how the discoverer found this solution for the very first time! 

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same issue right now. A cleanup helped. As I had cleanup issues with VS in the last time (some DB-lock prevents a real cleanup to happen), my working cleanup was this way:

1. Close VS.
2. Git Bash in solution folder: `git clean -xfd`

Probably it helps.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. It looks like your first post, if that is the case, I must say that it's once heck of an entrance to make :-)

Comment: I saw the "Uknown Project" in the test explorer results a few times when I moved tests between test DLLs with the XUnit test runner.  I found it was sufficient to delete the .vs folder which was in the same folder as my solution file.

Comment: I had the same problem again. The solution suggested by @pwretmo also worked for me, and is of course the better one, as it has less impact on the solution. The accepted answer should be changed.

Comment: This answer will remove anything that isn't in source control, so if you don't check in things like launchSettings.json, you may want to use pwretmo's answer instead.

Comment: @pwretmo answer is a safer and more direct answer to the specific problem.

Comment: The community has spoken. I have changed the accepted answer, to help others the best possible way. This answer was still fine for me, but I get the point that it can introduce certain risks. I am still very grateful for the help though :-).

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these solutions worked for me. I was able to get the test explorer working by **closing visual studio** and **deleting** the "**.vs**" folder. Then **reopen the solution** and let it rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Visual Studio developer community (found by going to the Help menu and selecting Feedback), an update to Visual Studio to version 16.5.5 will resolve the issue. FYI: They released this in February 2020

I can confirm it works (I was on VS 16.4.6)

Answer (score 0):

Steps as below

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Go to the project folder
3. Find the ".vs" folder. (Make sure you are also checking hidden item)
4. Delete ".vs" folder.
5. Good to go, Open visual studio, build and run project.